# Looping over tuples within a list?

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and I am working on a piece of code as follows:

```
list_of_tuples = [("Rachel",19,"red"),("Dan",20,"blue),("Hayley",19,"purple")]
```

What I want to do, is loop over the list and take an average of their ages, which is the second element of each tuple. I was thinking along the lines of:

```
for i in list_of_tuples:
    data = list(i)
    age_list = []
    age = data[1]
    age_list.append(age)
```

But this seems to be incorrect. Any help?

Comment: Move `age_list = []` outside the loop. As it stands, you are setting `age_list` to an empty list at each loop iteration.

Comment: There's no need for `data = list(i); age = data[1]`. You can index the tuple `i` straightaway in the same way as a list, and shorten this to `age = i[1]`. Of course, then you can shorten things to `age_list.append(i[1])` and leave out all other statements in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the `age_list` *before* the loop.

```py
list_of_tuples = [("Rachel",19,"red"),("Dan",20,"blue"),("Hayley",19,"purple")]

age_list = []
for i in list_of_tuples:
    data = list(i)
    age = data[1]
    age_list.append(age)

print age_list
```

Output:

```
[19, 20, 19]
```

---

**Edit 1:**

A much shorter solution would be:

```
print [t[1] for t in list_of_tuples]
```

**Edit 2:**

Then you can get the average as follows:

```
print sum(float(t[1]) for t in list_of_tuples) / len(list_of_tuples)
```

(Or with your for-loop: Initialize the average to be 0 before the loop and add `float(age) / len(list_of_tuples)` in each iteration.)

Comment: why use `data = list(i)` and `age = data[i]`, you can access a tuple by index just as you can a list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Sure. I'd chose to restrict to the necessary modifications only.

Comment: @Back2Basics: I thought the question was mainly on why the existing code does not yield the list of ages. But I added the average.

Answer (score 1):

First fix the ending double quotes on ("Dan",20,"blue)

Forget the loops.  They are slow.  You can do something with pandas dataframes.

```
list_of_tuples = [("Rachel",19,"red"),("Dan",20,"blue"),("Hayley",19,"purple")]
from pandas import DataFrame as DF
df = DF(list_of_tuples) #turns the data into a DataFrame
df[1].mean()
```

Comment: Why give an answer using pandas when a newbie asks a simple question?

Comment: I thought pandas was a simple way to approach this problem.  4 lines, no strange syntax, could be useful to this person going forward. If you thought pandas was hard, why would you think an easy answer is best?

Comment: I think it's fairly obvious that Anna is still learning how to work with basic Python data structures, so giving an answer that uses a fancy object from a non-standard module isn't going to help her learn how to use tuples & lists. Of course, if she'd mentioned pandas by name or tag in her question, a pandas-oriented answer would be entirely appropriate.

Comment: Sometimes people need to be told their assumptions or approach to solving a problem could be improved if they would only broaden their horizons.

Comment: Sure! Once they've mastered the basics. Otherwise, there's the danger of them getting overwhelmed by all the 3rd party packages out there. OTOH, (for example) if someone who'd been using Python for a few months was about to embark on something complex with urllib2, it would be entirely appropriate to save them from a world of pain and recommend that they use the requests module.

Comment: Language pedagogy is out of scope of this particular conversation.  This is a debate as long as time (technical schools vs. liberal arts education).  I don't believe someone needs to master anything (the basics change for every domain) in order to be able to be fast tracked to their intended destination when there is little risk involved and the reward is doing what you need to get done quickly (which becomes a huge incentive to master it).  As this is an interesting topic I would like to continue this discussion. But I'm not sure about what forum would be appropriate.

Comment: Well, we _could_ take it to Chat. But I suspect that neither of us is going to convince the other. :)

Answer (score 1):

As your tuples list have 3 index so with an iteration like `i,j,k in list_of_tuples` you can access to its elements over a loop and with `sum` function you can earn the sum of ages then divide sum to `len(list_of_tuples)` for calculate the average ! also you can use the index `1` for access to ages!

```
>>> sum([j for i,j,k in list_of_tuples])/len(list_of_tuples)
19
```

or

```
>>> sum([i[1] for i in list_of_tuples])/len(list_of_tuples)
19
```

Comment: IMO, your 2nd example is much better here, Kasra. We don't need the other fields in the tuple, so just getting the one we want using indexing is better than unpacking the whole tuple.